# CPython 3.9 python.gram file - Error when trying to run make regen-pegen with utf-8 text

Tags: python, utf-8, grammar, cpython, python-internals

I'm trying to create a custom Python version, with the ability to write the keywords in Hebrew.
I cloned CPython, and I tried to edit the `python.gram` file, in order to accept also Hebrew keywords.
for example, in the `for` keyword, I tried to do that:
Instead of:

```
for_stmt[stmt_ty]:
| 'for' t=star_targets 'in' ~ ex=star_expressions ':' tc=[TYPE_COMMENT] b=block el=[else_block] {
    _Py_For(t, ex, b, el, NEW_TYPE_COMMENT(p, tc), EXTRA) }
```

I tried to write:

```
for_stmt[stmt_ty]:
| ('עבור' | 'for') t=star_targets 'in' ~ ex=star_expressions ':' tc=[TYPE_COMMENT] b=block el=[else_block] {
    _Py_For(t, ex, b, el, NEW_TYPE_COMMENT(p, tc), EXTRA) }
```

But when I try to run `make regen-pegen` again, I get this error:
`AssertionError: 'עבור' is not a known literal`

There is something to do? Or utf-8 is not supported?

Thank's!

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar thing like you, only I added Chinese keywords. It works as below:

1. Pinpoint the error msg. It is in .\Tools\peg_generator\pegen\c_generator.py. Open the file, you can see a re.match line above the AssertionError. Modify the match pattern to suit your need.
2. run make regen-pegen to regenerate Parser/parser.c. You may also need to make minor changes to reserved_keywords[] starting from line 11 in this file. In my case, taking '函' (equivalent to 'def') for example, it appears inside the second { } before modification, but one Chinese char uses 3 bytes in utf-8, so it should be inside the fourth { } along with 'def'. Also mind the order.

Good luck and have fun!